# How to delete an artifactory directory named ${env.DateString} in curl command

Tags: linux, curl, interpolation, artifactory

I am trying to delete an artifactory directory named **${env.DateString}** But unable to interpolate properly. I escaped by using \ ${env.DateString} but somehow the brackets {} are being left out.
Directory path http://localhost:8080/artifactory/myrepo/Docker/${env.DateString}/

```
curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:<API-KEY>" -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/artifactory/myrepo/Docker/\${env.DateString}/
```

Error:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Could not locate artifact 'myrepo:Docker/$env.DateString' (Nothing to delete)."
  } ]
}[
```

Somehow the brackets in ${env.DateString} is missed when interpolating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the $ and. needs to be URL encoded. We can use the below API to delete the folder
curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api: -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/artifactory/myrepo/Docker/%24%7Benv.DateString%7D/